# How to load cache the data present in a table during server start up

Tags: spring, bootstrapping

I am developing a java web application in which I want to cache all the data present in a table during server start up.

Also if there are any changes in DB values, I wish to refresh the cache (without restarting the server).

I am looking for some material in spring which may help me in achieving that. But I am not able to figure it out.

Please help how can I achieve the same. Also I would like to initialize some beans on server start up.

Comment: Start reading the docs. Hibernate and spring ?

Answer (score 1):

To start with read the following docs which will get you started.

Refer to Spring document http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Also check this simple tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/cache-support-spring-3-1-m1/

Regarding your bean initialization you can use @PostConstruct annotation on a method of the bean class. Spring will call that method after the bean is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

The application that your planning to build wouldnt be an easy one. In my experience, creating an application like that would require a knowledge of the following:
1. Spring
2. Ehcache
3. JMX
4. Servlet Listeners